# Добавить шрифт в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть файл .ttf с нужным мне шрифтом, как его подгрузить в tkinter? Есть какие-то способы?

Comment: Как добавить файл шрифта .ttf в код Python, чтобы его можно было увидеть на любом компьютере? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76221689/how-to-add-ttf-font-file-to-python-code-so-that-it-can-be-seen-on-any-computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть способ как загрузить пользовательский шрифт в TKinter и чтобы это работало

1-ое решение:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()

custom_font_path = "сюда_полный_путь_к_шрифту"
custom_font = font.Font(family="CustomFont", size=12, name="custom_font")
custom_font.configure(family=custom_font_path)

label = Label(root, text="Hello world!", font=custom_font)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Может произойти так, что он не загрузит твой шрифт. Если это так и произошло, то попробуй 2 способ.

2-ое решение:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

root = Tk()

# Загрузка пользовательского шрифта
custom_font_path = "сюда_полный_путь_к_шрифту"
custom_font_size = 24
custom_font = ImageFont.truetype(custom_font_path, custom_font_size)

# Создание изображения с текстом, используя пользовательский шрифт
image = Image.new("RGB", (300, 100), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((10, 10), "Hello, World!", font=custom_font, fill="black")
image.save("text_image.png")

# Отображение изображения в Tkinter
photo = PhotoImage(file="text_image.png")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo  # чтобы изображение не удалилось из памяти
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Я надеюсь что я решил твою проблему :)